# Classic ASP Access Database Connection Trouble

Tags: html, ms-access, asp-classic

I am in need of using Classic ASP with Access. This is a requirement unfortunately. I currently have a script which connects to the Access DB just fine. Here is the snippet:

```
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db1.mdb")

Set rsGuestbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strSQL = "SELECT * from table1;"

rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
```

Again, this snippet works just fine, records sent to browser.

When I apply this connection to a different script, I get an error returned which states:
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0415' 
Expected literal constant
Const ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)} DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db1.mdb")

Here is the connection snippet:

```
Const ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db1.mdb")
```

Appreciate any guidance anyone can throw my way, I know this is some old school, anyone else remeber when this stuff was bleeding edge? LOL I do...

Comment: lol but MS Access was NEVER bleeding edge!

Comment: nothing wrong with that code - how is the ConnectionString constant value used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a constant for your connection string. Since `Server.MapPath` is indeterminate (paths could change from one run to the next), `Const` is complaining. Or, it might complain with any concatenation when assigning a constant, I can't remember for sure...

Instead, change:

```
Const ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db1.mdb")
```

to:

```
Dim ConnectionString 
ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db1.mdb")
```